# can't insert data into many-to-many table

Tags: postgresql

Maybe I'm stupid, but I can't understand what is wrong

```
CREATE TABLE groups 
(
    id UUID primary key,
    label TEXT,
    created_at timestamp default current_timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp default current_timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE filters 
(
    id UUID primary key,
    type TEXT,
    created_at timestamp default current_timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp default current_timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE filters_in_groups 
(
    group_id UUID NULL references groups(id),
    filter_id UUID NULL references filters(id),
    created_at timestamp default current_timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp default current_timestamp
);
```

I have such a structure but I can't insert data into `filters_in_groups`

```
DO
$_gen_filters_$
declare
  group_id UUID;
  filter_id UUID
begin
    group_id := gen_random_uuid();
    filter_id := gen_random_uuid();
    INSERT INTO groups 
    values (
          group_id,
          lower(faker.word()),
          NOW(),
          NOW()
    );

    filter_id := gen_random_uuid();
    insert into filters
    values (
        filter_id,
        'text',
        NOW(),
        NOW()
    );

    insert into filters_in_groups
    values (
        group_id,
        filter_id,
        NOW(),
        NOW()
   );
END;
$_gen_filters_$;
```

it fails with an error

> SQL Error [23503]: ERROR: insert or update on table "filters_in_groups" violates foreign key constraint "filters_in_groups_filter_id_fkey"
> Detail: Key (filter_id)=(eeb1101d-2b10-4497-be10-f6f0c8ee5dd3) is not present in table "filters".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: a) don't assign `filter_id := gen_random_uuid();` twice b) `updated_at` makes no sense for a relationship table c) try specifying the columns in your `insert` clauses

Comment: well, I'm making 3 inserts to `filters`, to `groups`, and to `filters_in_groups`, and even If with such a structure I'm doing it by hand through UI: 1) create row in `filters`, create  row id `groups`, create row in  `filters_in_groups` it still failing

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/cmYAZF_Y) with the code you posted (after fixing the missing semicolon and replacing the `faker` call with some string)

Comment: [The error happens](https://dbfiddle.uk/JWqEjsil) when you flip the column order in your table definition (or in the `insert`) - again, specify the column names in the `insert`

Comment: and semicolon is typo I made only here

Comment: My be, ``insert into filters`` fails by any reason. Then `` is not present in table``. Manually check presence of key before insert.